# Using the same codes in all test cases

Tags: testing, methods, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I want to create a header to use in all of my test cases. For example:

```
WebUI.openBrowser(GlobalVariable.appURL)
WebUI.maximizeWindow()
WebUI.waitForPageLoad(0)
```

Lets say I use these 3 lines in every test case I have. How can I put this in a single block(method, class etc) so that I can call it in all of my cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to Report Listeners and add:

```
@BeforeTestCase
def setupBeforeTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext){
    WebUI.openBrowser(GlobalVariable.appURL)
    WebUI.maximizeWindow()
    WebUI.waitForPageLoad(0)
}
```

This will run before each test case. You could also add a tear down method, like this:

```
@AfterTestCase
def tearDownAtfetTestCase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext){
    WebUI.closeBrowser()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best way would be to create a test case for this and call it for example openBrowser. The main content you can put in another test case, and both together in a test suite. So you can re-use your test case for all other test suites.